# ACER Aspire AX1920-UR10P

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

So I killed the original hard drive, and bought a new one and do not have a boot disk.  I got the driver files from ACER's website and I have a downloaded copy of Windows 7 but I can't the computer to do anything but tell me to reboot and select the proper boot device.  Any advice.

Comment: How you are burning your disk. your disk isn't bootable.

Answer (score 1):

Burn the windows 7 to a DVD and put it in your dvd drive, Turn on the computer, and  press F12 to access the Boot Menu, choose your DVD Drive, and just follow the installation. If that doesn't work, then press f2 as the computer starts to access the BIOS, and choose the dvd drive, to boot from.

Comment: for new hard disk it will automatically take the dvd as it will not find any other bootable disk, it seems the disk isn't bootable.